# Combining UnitMass and UnitLength arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, anyobject

I'm trying to combine two measurement arrays:

```
var unitMasses: [UnitMass] {
    return [.milligrams, .grams, .kilograms, .ounces, .pounds]
}

var unitLengths: [UnitLength] {
    return [.centimeters, .decimeters, .meters]
}
```

into one:

```
var units: [AnyObject] {
    // This works:
    return [unitMasses].flatMap{$0}
    // But I've tried the following and this doesn't:
    //return ([unitMasses as AnyObject] + [unitVolumes as AnyObject]).flatMap{$0}
}
```

I want to be able able to  to access the `.symbol` attribute of the elements in the `units` variable:

```
var symbols: [String] {
    return units.map({ unit in unit.symbol })
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I thought that they were classes? "The NSUnitVolume class is an Dimension subclass that encapsulates units of measure for volume."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view this way is quite more straight forward.I do not see any needs to merge arrays before.

```
var symbols = unitMasses.map({$0.symbol})
symbols += unitLengths.map({$0.symbol})

print(symbols) // ["mg", "g", "kg", "oz", "lb", "cm", "dm", "m"]
```

Comment: I'd also point out that the map can be done like... `unitMasses.map{ $0.symbol }` :D

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks - not sure that convention is for me ...! A bit ugly

Comment: @Oleg Gordiichuk Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works well. For completeness, this is how I used it:

```
var units: [Dimension] {
    return unitMasses.map({ unit in unit }) + unitLengths.map({ unit in unit })
}

var symbols: [String] {
    return units.map({ unit in unit.symbol })
}
```